# spring-boot executable war/jar can't found JSP, but in intellij IDE it works

Tags: maven, jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot

It is my configuration.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
...
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>{MainClass}</mainClass>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
                <attach>true</attach>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

In IntelliJ, It works well.
But when I run using java command

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

It is not found JSP file in the path.
I googled this problem. and I change jar to war.
But It didn't work. 
What should I do?
Should not use executable jar with JSP?

Here is a log. (when run using java command)

```
No matching bean found for view name 'user/ticket_list'
No matching bean found for view name 'user/ticket_list.html'
Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'user/ticket_list'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/user/ticket_list.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'user/ticket_list'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/user/ticket_list.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Here is log (when run using intellij

```
No matching bean found for view name 'user/ticket_list'
Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'user/ticket_list'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/user/ticket_list.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'user/ticket_list'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/user/ticket_list.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
Added model object 'locations' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'user/ticket_list'
Added model object 'location' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'user/ticket_list'
Added model object 'tickets' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'user/ticket_list'
Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/user/ticket_list.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'user/ticket_list'
Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error log?

Comment: There is not error log. In the client it has http 404

Comment: Error log is just 'jsp file not found' in the server no error log.

Comment: Could you please add this line to your properties and try again?

`logging.level.org.springframework.web= debug`

this will give the web access logs and may have some clues there

Comment: Did you include `src/main/webapp` to your resources?

Comment: I mean are your jsp files located in webapp folder?

Comment: My jsp files are in src/main/resource/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/views

Comment: @webmaster I add log. Could you check?

Comment: Wel it seems like the code is ending where you populate the model variables for the page, how are you populating those values? from db?

Comment: Well I don't know if you started coding newly but to solve the bugs, you must concentrate on the consistent symptoms; by adding that log level line we got a clue now, it is about populating the model variables I guess because the app finds the related JSP files as it is working in IntelliJ so please concentrate on those. You gotta catch the consistent things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPs in executable JARs are not supported by Boot.

It may have worked in the past using hacks/workarounds, but it's always been documented see [JSP limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) and [spring-boot#8022](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8022).